# How does this primality test make the code 5000x faster?

Tags: c++, stl, set, primes, gmp

Warning: This code is a solution for Project Euler [Problem 50](https://projecteuler.net/problem=50). If you don't want it spoiled, don't look here.

Here I have code that searches for a long sequence of consecutive prime numbers, which summed together are also a prime. At one point, I need to test whether a sum is prime.

I have two tests, which are ifdef'd in the function computeMaxPrime. The first checks the sum against a std::set of prime numbers. The second uses a Miller-Rabin test implemented by GMP. The function only gets called 6 times. When I use the first test, the function computeMaxPrime takes .12 seconds. When I use the second test, it only takes ~.00002 seconds. Can someone explain how that's possible? I wouldn't think 6 calls to check whether a number is in a set would take 100 ms. I also tried using an unordered_set, and it performs the same.

I thought that maybe it was a timing issue, but I've verified it via timing the whole program execution from Terminal (on OSX). I've also verified that if I change the test to use the Miller-Rabin test first, and then confirm using the set, it makes a single call to the set and the clock reports .02 seconds, exactly what I would expect (1/6th the total time of only using the set test).

```
#include "PrimeGenerator2.h"
#include <set>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <gmp.h>

typedef std::set<u_int64t>       intSet;

bool isInIntSet (intSet       set,
                 u_int64t     key)
{
  return (set.count(key) > 0);
}

bool isPrime (u_int64t key)
{
  mpz_t      integ;

  mpz_init (integ);
  mpz_set_ui (integ, key);
  return (mpz_probab_prime_p (integ, 25) > 0);
}

void computeInitialData (const u_int64t   limit,
                         intSet      *primeSet,
                         intList     *sumList,
                         u_int64t    *maxCountUpperBound)
{
  PrimeSieve     sieve;
  u_int64t     cumSum = 0;
  u_int64t     pastUpperBound = 0;

  *maxCountUpperBound = 0;

  for (u_int64t prime = sieve.NextPrime(); prime < limit; prime = sieve.NextPrime()) {
    primeSet->insert(prime);

    cumSum += prime;
    sumList->push_back(cumSum);
    if (cumSum < limit)
      (*maxCountUpperBound)++;
    else
      pastUpperBound++;
  }
}

u_int64t computeMaxPrime (const u_int64t   limit,
                          const intSet  &primeSet,
                          const intList &sumList,
                          const u_int64t   maxCountUpperBound)
{
  for (int maxCount = maxCountUpperBound; ; maxCount--) {
    for (int i = 0; i + maxCount < sumList.size(); i++) {
      u_int64t   sum;

      sum = sumList[maxCount + i] - sumList[i];
      if (sum > limit)
        break;
#if 0
      if (isInIntSet (primeSet, sum))
        return sum;
#else
      if (isPrime (sum))
        return sum;
#endif
    }
  }

  return 0; // This should never happen
}

u_int64t findMaxCount (const u_int64t   limit)
{ 
  intSet       primeSet;  // Contains the set of all primes < limit
  intList      sumList; // Array of cumulative sums of primes

  u_int64t     maxCountUpperBound = 0;  // Used an initial guess for the maximum count
  u_int64t     maxPrime;          // Final return value

  clock_t      time0, time1, time2;

  time0     = clock();
  computeInitialData (limit, &primeSet, &sumList, &maxCountUpperBound);
  time1     = clock();
  maxPrime  = computeMaxPrime (limit, primeSet, sumList, maxCountUpperBound);
  time2     = clock();  

  printf ("%f seconds for primes \n"  , (double)(time1 - time0)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  printf ("%f seconds for search \n"  , (double)(time2 - time1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);  

  return maxPrime;
}

int main(void)
{
  printf ("%lld\n", findMaxCount(1000000));
}
```

EDIT: Oh it's even weirder. Appears to have nothing to do with the STL set. If I do a hack to make isInIntSet just check how many times it's been called, it's equally slow compared to the GMP test. This makes me think I've likely just run across a compiler bug (EDIT2: Never blame the compiler!)

```
bool isInIntSet (intSet set, u_int64t key)
{
  static int  counter = 0;
  counter++;
  return (counter == 6);
}
```

Comment: std::count is logarithmic to the size.  What's the size of your set and where does the number 6 come from?

Comment: The number 6 was just me using a static counter to see how many times the function gets called. I just made an edit; it appears that set and std::count have nothing to do with it. Even a trivial hack function (which does end up computing the same result) is slow.

Comment: OK.  Something doesn't quite add up.  There should be ~60k primes under 1M.  Your count upper bound is going to be on the order of 500 (just guessing).  You have these nested loops trying to find the series...  How could you be calling this only 6 times?

Comment: Yeah the count upper bound is between 500 and 600 (good guess!). You're right, 6 *does* seem really low. I even added printf's into the function to verify it (6 lines were printed).

Comment: Well, that may be the case (odd but still) but keep in mind you're not just measuring the time to call the function but also the time spent in the loops just hitting your break statement.  anyways, something doesn't add up.  Step through with the debugger...

Comment: Right, but if that were the root of the time than switching between the tests shouldn't make such a large difference in the time. I'll run it through in the debugger.

Comment: Use a bit vector for the set and initialize it using a sieve.

Comment: Ah yeah, that's a good tip Brian, thanks.

Comment: Next time you have a performance question, one of the first things to try is using a profiler. It would have told you immediately that all the time was spent in std::set copy-constructor and destructor, and you would have guessed the reason in less that a minute.

Comment: Marc - yes you're absolutely right. I usually do go straight to a profiler, but I just blanked in this case for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duh. The function isInIntSet is taking an intSet as an argument directly, so the entire set is being copied. I meant to pass by reference (intSet &set). That takes the search time down to .000003 seconds with an unordered_set.

Comment: Great question of yours and quick answer, saved a lot time :D